# How to get back on Main thread in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, dispatch-queue

I am using my SignUpViewController to create an account, and when a user signs up for an account with a password that does NOT fit the password specifications, the program should throw an alert. For some reason instead, I keep getting:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished] may only be called from the main thread.'

How can I get back onto the main thread so that the program will just throw an alert?

Here is the code for that view controller:

```
@IBAction func signupPressed(_ sender: Any) {
     // Get a reference to the user pool
    let userPool = AppDelegate.defaultUserPool()
    // Collect all of the attributes that should be included in the signup call
        let emailAttribute = AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType(name: "email", value: self.email.text!)
        let firstNameAttribute = AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType(name: "given_name", value: self.firstName.text!)
        let lastNameAttribute = AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType(name: "family_name", value: self.lastName.text!)
        let birthdayAttribute = AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType(name: "birthdate", value: self.birthday.text!)
    // Actually make the signup call passing in those attributes

        userPool.signUp(UUID().uuidString, password: self.password.text!, userAttributes: [emailAttribute, firstNameAttribute, lastNameAttribute, birthdayAttribute], validationData: nil)
        .continueWith { (response) -> Any? in
            if response.error != nil {
                // Error in the signup process
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: response.error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler:nil))
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            } else {
                self.user = response.result!.user
                // Does user need verification?
                if (response.result?.userConfirmed?.intValue != AWSCognitoIdentityUserStatus.confirmed.rawValue) {
                    // User needs confirmation, so we need to proceed to the verify view controller
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "VerifySegue", sender: self)
                    }
                } else {
                    // User signed up but does not need verification
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                }
            }
            return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: You already have the right code you need - `DispatchQueue.main.async`. Just be sure to use for *all* UI being used in the background - including showing the alert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This also a main thread work

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { 
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: response.error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler:nil))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Btw you can have only 1 `DispatchQueue.main.async` to surround the response , if all things need to be done in main

Answer (score 2):

In your closure, where if error is not nil, can you update the code like following and try again:

```
if response.error != nil {
    // Error in the signup process     
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: response.error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler:nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)    
    }
}
```

Comment: `UIKit` elements should be created on the thread they are displayed on

Comment: Thanks, updating the answer, although there are already other 3 answers so fast :D

Answer (score 2):

Just write

```
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

inside a Dispatch.main.async as you already did for the other segues

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are already marshalling presenting the view controller and performing segue with `DispatchQueue.main.async`. You should also do this to display the `UIAlertController`. You might as well just marshal the entire method body to the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Along with `DispatchQueue.main.async`, we can add `[weak self]` check to avoid retain cycle, like

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
    self?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```